# Node Promises Bluebird Collections API and Spread() Questions

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am trying to utilize a promise chain using Bluebirds Collection features.

one of the scripts for example:

```
var rest = require("./promisified_restler.js");
function memory(token) {
    CHECK='cfDJO9im';
    URL='https://monitoring.api.foo.com/v1.0/833/';
    SLUG='entities/en5mKIvs/checks/';
    MODE='/test';

    url = CHECK+URL+SLUG+CHECK+MODE
    headers = { headers:
        { "X-Auth-Token": token }
    }
    return rest.post(url, headers);
}


module.exports = memory;
```

Main script:

```
var getToken = require('./get_token.js');
var memory = require('./memory.js');
var cpu = require('./cpu.js');
var http = require('./http.js');
var httpPort = require('./http_port.js');
var network = require('./network.js');

getToken()
.catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
})
.all([cpu(token), memory(token)]).spread(function(cpu_result,
            memory_result) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(cpu_result));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(memory_result));
            });
```

1. How can I pass the token value to each function that returns a promise object?
2. What happens to Promise.all() if one of the promise objects return rejected? Does .all() stop, return false, and not finish the rest of the items in the array?
3. Do the functions/promise objects run parallel?
4. Is it possible to have spread() accept just one argument and it be applied for each value returned? Example:
   `.spread(function(returnedValue) {console.log(JSON.stringify(returnedValue)); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `.all()` wrong, it doesn't take any arguments (the static version does). It's not needed anyway if you are going to `.spread`.

Promises don't run anything, they just tell you when something has ran. You are the one calling some function to start I/O - if you then call another function on the next line synchronously, then both run concurrently. If you instead call the another function after the first one has completed, they run sequentially. The `Promise.all` would only give you a view of this when both are completed, it doesn't have anything else to do with them.

I don't understand 1. and 4.. Here's code:

```
getToken()
    .then(function(token) {
        return [cpu(token), memory(token)];
    })
    .spread(function(cpu_result, memory_result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cpu_result));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(memory_result));
    })
    /*
    This is totally unnecessary because unhandled errors are logged anyway.
    Uncomment if you want to actually handle the error
    .catch(function(e) {
       console.log(e);
    });
    */
```